# member operators not working

Tags: c++

i created a namespace and within that namespace a class. the class is called polynomial. i created public member operators to perform arithmetic operations between polynomial objects. however, when i try to use them in main, they dont give the right output.

i am not to sure if my error is on the definition or the way am using them.

here is are part of the files i am working on:

header | polynomial.h

```
#ifndef _POLYNOMIAL_H_
#define _POLYNOMIAL_H_
//...
namespace algebra {
  class polynomial {
    std::vector<double> coeffStorage;
   public:
    //...
    double operator()(double x);
    polynomial operator+(polynomial p);
    polynomial& operator+=(polynomial p);
    polynomial operator-();
    polynomial operator-(polynomial p);
    polynomial& operator-=(polynomial p);
    polynomial operator*(polynomial p);
    polynomial& operator*=(polynomial p);
  };

polynomial operator+(double c, polynomial p);
polynomial operator*(double c, polynomial p);
//...
}

#endif
```

cpp | polynomial.cpp

```
//...
//evaluates the polynomial at x
double algebra::polynomial::operator()(double x) {
  double result = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
   result += std::pow(x, i) * getCoeff(i);

  return result;
}

algebra::polynomial algebra::polynomial::operator+(algebra::polynomial p) {
  algebra::polynomial result;

  result.resize(degree() + p.degree() + 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
    result.setCoeff(i, (getCoeff(i) + p.getCoeff(i)));

  return result;
}

algebra::polynomial& algebra::polynomial::operator+=(algebra::polynomial p) {
  return ((*this) = (*this) + p);
}

algebra::polynomial algebra::polynomial::operator-() {
  algebra::polynomial result;

  for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
    result.setCoeff(i, -1 * getCoeff(i));

  return result;
}

algebra::polynomial algebra::polynomial::operator-(algebra::polynomial p) {
  return ((*this) + -p);
}

algebra::polynomial& algebra::polynomial::operator-=(algebra::polynomial p) {
  return ((*this) = (*this) - p);
}

algebra::polynomial algebra::polynomial::operator*(algebra::polynomial p) {
  algebra::polynomial result;
  double coeffSum = 0.0;

  result.resize(degree() + p.degree() + 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
    coeffSum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
      coeffSum = getCoeff(j) * p.getCoeff(i - j);
    }
    result.setCoeff(i, coeffSum);
  }
  return result;
}

algebra::polynomial& algebra::polynomial::operator*=(algebra::polynomial p) {
  return ((*this) = (*this) * p);
}

algebra::polynomial algebra::operator+(double c, polynomial p) {
  algebra::polynomial result = p;

  result.setCoeff(0, c + p.getCoeff(0));

  return result;
}

algebra::polynomial algebra::operator*(double c, polynomial p) {
  algebra::polynomial result = p;

  for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
    result.setCoeff(i, c * p.getCoeff(i));

  return result;
}
//...
```

the coefficients of a polynomial are store in a vector. each index belongs to the degree of the polynomial. for example, 2x^2 + 3 looks like 3*x^0 + 0*x^1 + 2*x^2 and it is stored as {3.0, 0.0, 2.0} on the vector.

i plan to use the operators in main as follows:

```
algebra::polynomial p2;
  p2.setCoeff(0, 1);
  p2.setCoeff(1, 1);
  algebra::polynomial p3;
  p3.setCoeff(0, -1);
  p3.setCoeff(1, 1);

  algebra::polynomial px;
  px = p2 + p3;

  algebra::polynomial py;
  py = p3 * p2;
```

but px and py turn out to be empty.

Comment: It will be better if you can post a [mcve].

Comment: Have you verified the input and output at each step?  i.e. Is setCoeff setting correctly, etc?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, without a complete example is hard to determine where is failing, because we don't know what are exactly doing the methods: `degree()`, `getCoeff(i)`, `setCoeff(i, c)` and `resize(sz)` but I'll try:

If I assume that:

- `degree()` returns 1 in both of the polynomial in your example,
- `resize(n)` simply calls to `std::vector::resize` method,
- `size()` simply calls to `std::vector::size` method
- `getCoeff(i)` and `setCoeff(i, c)` get and alter the `i-esim` vector element;

Then the logic is wrong in both operators (+ and *):

- In operator + the vector is resized to 3, and loop gets 3 elements of both input vectors (but they both have only 2 elements!). The resize must use the greater degree +1.
- In operator * the vector is also resized to 3 (which is fine), but the loop logic to get polynomial multiplication is wrong, getting elements that doesn't exist in the vectors (Ex. see when `i=2` and `j=0`: `p.getCoeff(i-j) == p.getCoeff(2)`.

Besides that, you can use `std::vector::operator[]` and `std::vector::resize` instead `getCoeff`, `setCoeff` and `resize` methods while you're inside your own class (even because `polynomial::resize` should be private, it doesn't make sense to me to resize polynomial from outside the class).

The corrected methods are:

```
algebra::polynomial algebra::polynomial::operator+(algebra::polynomial p) {
    algebra::polynomial result;
    int maxDegree = std::max(p.degree(), degree());
    result.coeffStorage.resize(maxDegree + 1, 0.0);
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxDegree; i++) {
        double value = (i <= degree() ? coeffStorage[i] : 0)
                + (i <= p.degree() ? p.coeffStorage[i] : 0);
        result.coeffStorage[i] = value;
    }
    return result;
}

algebra::polynomial algebra::polynomial::operator*(algebra::polynomial p) {
    algebra::polynomial result;
    int resultDegree = degree() + p.degree();
    result.coeffStorage.resize(resultDegree + 1, 0.0);
    for (int i = 0; i <= degree(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= p.degree(); j++) {
            result.coeffStorage[i + j] += coeffStorage[i] * p.coeffStorage[j];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now, in polynomial operations, some coefficients may be zero, if that occurs with the one with greater power, the degree decreases, so the method `degree()` must be calculated and not necessarily will be `size()-1`. Something like:

```
int algebra::polynomial::degree() const {
    int d = std::max(0u, coeffStorage.size() - 1); 
    while(d > 0 && coeffStorage[d] == 0.0)
        d--;
    return d;
}
```

A shorter/better way to get or set a coefficient could be using `operator[]` instead of `getCoeff` and `setCoeff` like this (maybe better if you add an upper limit validation too):

```
double &algebra::polynomial::operator[](size_t i) {
    if (i + 1 > coeffStorage.size())
        coeffStorage.resize(i + 1, 0.0);
    return coeffStorage[i];
}
```

Finally, to print results it's better if the printing is human readable with a method like this:

```
std::string algebra::polynomial::str() const {
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (int d = degree(), i = d; i >= 0; i--) {
        double c = coeffStorage[i];
        if (c != 0) {
            if (!std::signbit(c) && i < d)
                ss << '+';
            if (i == 0 || c != 1.0)
                ss << c;
            if (i > 0)
                ss << "y"; // "x" can be confused with "*"?
            if (i > 1)
                ss << i;
        }
    }
    return ss.str();
}
```

These methods allow us to make tests like this:

```
int main() {
    algebra::polynomial pa, pb;
    // 4a² + 2a + 3
    pa[2] = 4; pa[1] = 2; pa[0] = 3;
    // 5a³ + 2
    pb[3] = 5; pb[0] = 2;
    std::cout << "pa = " << pa.str() << ", " << "pb = " << pb.str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pa + pb = " << (pa + pb).str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pa * pb = " << (pa * pb).str() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which console output is:

```
pa = 4y2+2y+3, pb = 5y3+2
pa + pb = 5y3+4y2+2y+5
pa * pb = 20y5+10y4+15y3+8y2+4y+6
```